# Dividing a list into two lists

Tags: python, list

Below is my current training_list;

```
Training_list = [37, 0.7173543689320389, None, None, 9, 0.3351132686084142, 0.05165857605177993, 0.2942961165048544, 0.8373381877022654, 0.6119741100323625, 0, 0, 45, None, ' <=50K'], [46, 0.7173543689320389, None, None, 13, 0.03673139158576052, 0.13199838187702265, 0.3013349514563107, 0.8373381877022654, 0.38802588996763754, 0, 0, 25, None, ' <=50K'], [44, 0.7173543689320389, None, None, 9, 0.1610032362459547, 0.12823624595469255, 0.3013349514563107, 0.8373381877022654, 0.6119741100323625, 0, 0, 40, None, ' >50K']
```

I need to divide the list into two lists based on the last attribute ' <=50K' or ' >50K'
I want to exclude the last attribute as well from both lists.
I tried the below code and i'm getting the following:

```
under 50k list
[]
```

Code is as follows;

```
over_50k = []
under_50k = []
for row in training_list:
        if row[-1].lstrip() == " <=50K":
            under_50k.append(row[:-1])
        elif row [-1].lstrip() == " >50K":
            over_50k.append(row[:-1])

print("under 50k list")
print(under_50k)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is :

```
Training_list = [11,22,33,44,55,77,99,0.333,None,"<=50K"],[33,0.3344,88,44,55,11,None,"<=50K"],[22,44,0.334455,11,44,66,">50K"]

liste =[]
under_50k =[]
over_50k =[]
i=0
while 1:
    try:
        liste = Training_list[i]
        i+=1
    except:
        break
    if liste[len(liste)-1] == '<=50K':
        under_50k.append(liste)
    if liste[len(liste)-1] == '>50K':
        over_50k.append(liste)

print("under",under_50k)
print("over",over_50k)
```

And the output is :

```
under [[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 77, 99, 0.333, None, '<=50K'], [33, 0.3344, 88, 44, 55, 11, None, '<=50K']]
over [[22, 44, 0.334455, 11, 44, 66, '>50K']]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You're using `lstrip()`.
2. `lstrip()` will remove leading whitespace.
3. The string `" <=50K"` has leading whitespace.

So we might try to compare against a string that has no leading whitespace:

```
if row[-1].strip() == "<=50K":
```

Or perhaps:

```
under_50k = [row[:-1] for row in training_list if row[-1].strip() == "<=50K"]
over_50k  = [row[:-1] for row in training_list if row[-1].strip() == ">50K"]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want optimization: one for can do that

```
under_50k = []
over_50k = []
for x in training_list:
    if x[-1].strip() == "<=50k":
        under_50k.append(x[:-1])
    if x[-1].strip() == ">=50k":
        over_50k.append(x[:-1])
```

using itertools.groupby:

```
>>> for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(Training_list,key=lambda x:x[1]),key = lambda x:x[-1]=="<=50K" and "under" or "over"):
...     print x,list(y)
... 
under [[33, 0.3344, 88, 44, 55, 11, None, '<=50K'], [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 77, 99, 0.333, None, '<=50K']]
over [[22, 44, 0.334455, 11, 44, 66, '>50K']]
```